# Ruby Gem Nokogiri Not Installing on Rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to run a Rails app through **Docker** that is using `Rails 3.2.11`.  The gem **nokogiri** is not being installed when I run `bundle install`.

I have this in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.8.rc2'
```

And this in my LOCK file:

```
nokogiri (1.6.8.rc2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
```

When I try running bundle install through docker, I get the following error messages:

```
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.3.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.3... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.3... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.3... ERROR, review
'/var/www/docker_example/activemodel/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.rc2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.3/compile.log'
to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/bash
/var/www/docker_example/activemodel/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.rc2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.3/libxml2-2.9.3/missing
aclocal-1.15 -I m4
/var/www/docker_example/activemodel/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.rc2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.3/libxml2-2.9.3/missing:
line 81: aclocal-1.15: command not found
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.15' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
        --help
        --clean
        --use-system-libraries
        --enable-static
        --disable-static
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --enable-cross-build
        --disable-cross-build
/var/www/docker_example/activemodel/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block
in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
from /var/www/docker_example/activemodel/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in
`chdir'
from /var/www/docker_example/activemodel/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in
`execute'
from /var/www/docker_example/activemodel/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in
`compile'
from /var/www/docker_example/activemodel/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in
`cook'
        from extconf.rb:288:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
        from extconf.rb:181:in `block in chdir_for_build'
        from extconf.rb:180:in `chdir'
        from extconf.rb:180:in `chdir_for_build'
        from extconf.rb:287:in `block in process_recipe'
        from extconf.rb:186:in `tap'
        from extconf.rb:186:in `process_recipe'
        from extconf.rb:477:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/www/docker_example/activemodel/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.rc2 for
inspection.
Results logged to /var/www/docker_example/activemodel/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.rc2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.8.rc2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.rc2'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  fog was resolved to 1.23.0, which depends on
    nokogiri
```

I've tried modifying the Gem File a few times but it keeps resulting in Nokogiri not being installed properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try googling the error message?

Comment: The first result on google: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33279062/1954610

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `libxml2` is installed on your machine. Is it available to install with `brew install` or `apt-get install` depending on your OS.

Update: also if you're trying to run your app inside of docker container add `libxml2` too and install nokogiri with `RUN gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1'` in your Dockerfile

Comment: I'm trying to install `libxml2` on my Windows 10 Machine but I don't have `apt-get` on my machine.  Is there a repo I could clone to install these dependencies?