# LFS CoreUtils-8.30 fails with aclocal-1.15 missing

Tags: linux, linux-from-scratch

I have a standard core i5 laptop and I'm trying to make LFS (Linux From Scratch) it has all worked fine (after a couple of retries) until I try and make Coreutils-8.30 when I do the Make I get:

```
lfs@robert-HP-EliteBook-8760w:/mnt/lfs/sources/coreutils-8.30$ make
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh /mnt/lfs/sources/coreutils-8.30/build-aux/missing aclocal-1.15 -I m4
/mnt/lfs/sources/coreutils-8.30/build-aux/missing: line 81: aclocal-1.15: command not found
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.15' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
Makefile:6034: recipe for target 'aclocal.m4' failed
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
```

I've gone around and around on this and I'm not getting anywhere. I've found a couple of references to gettext but that hasn't helped.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: [How to overcome “'aclocal-1.15' is missing on your system” warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33278928/608639) And more generally, ["aclocal-1.15: command not found"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22aclocal-1.15%3A+command+not+found%22).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overcome "'aclocal-1.15' is missing on your system" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33278928/608639)

Answer (score 1):

Just got through the same issue. You need to install libtool-bin, automake and makeinfo

## sudo apt-get install  libtool-bin automake makeinfo

Then run autoreconf -f -i in the mpfr directory. After that you can run ./configure etc.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when I applied the patch for coreutils that was provided in the downloads. I noticed the instructions did not tell me to apply this patch at this step so I tried to build again without the patch applied and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just met and solved this problem，My solution is not necessarily the best。
This questions because you don't have "aclocal" tools with version 1.15,
This tools provided by automake-1.15, which depended by autoconf-2.69 or later.
So My solution is installing autoconf-2.69 and automake-1.15:
  1. installing autoconf-2.69
     `tar -xvf autoconf-2.69.tar.xz`
     `./configure --prefix=/tools`
     `make && make install`
  2. installing automake-1.15
    `tar -xvf automake-1.15.tar.xz`
     `./configure --prefix=/tools`
     `make && make install`
then you can compile your coreutils-8.30

Answer (score 0):

Check if autoinfo from gettext is installed OK.

This error when building coreutils is caused by absence of autopoint.